# Spring MVC Thymeleaf : Object parameter attributes value is always null

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass the differents form values to controller with object parameter like this :

in my view i've :

```
<form id="line_form" action="#" th:object="${lineFilter}" method="post">
<input type="text" id="nameHolder" th:field="*{msisdn}">
<input type="text" id="nameHolder" th:field="*{nameHolder}">
...
</form>
```

And in my controller, i've this method :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/listFilteredByAccount", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public DatatablesResponse<LineVO> getLineFilteredListWithAccount(LineFilter lineFilter, @DatatablesParams DatatablesCriterias criterias, Model model, Locale locale, HttpServletRequest req, String entity)
```

In my method controller, the fields of lineFilter are always null
I can call previous method with button also

Also, the url was called by dataTable like this :

```
dt:url="@{/orders/listFilteredByAccount}"
```

what i've forgot for set the good values of fields ?

I'm using Thymeleaf with Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@ModelAttribute` in your controller method

```
public DatatablesResponse<LineVO> getLineFilteredListWithAccount(@ModelAttribute("lineFilter") LineFilter lineFilter, ..and the rest of your params...)
```

Set your form action to `th:action="@{/orders/listFilteredByAccount}"`

Try adding this to your controller `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, ...)` since you're doing a post in your form.